# Черный экран Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Очень необычная ситуация, недавно поменял на компе SSD (В Биосе все сделал), и добавил оперативку 4гб (Ubuntu видит все хорошо), поставил Ubuntu (не двойная а простая загрузка, установка на флекшу загрузил образ через UNetbootin, версия Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa LTS.) , все было хорошо но через два дня , ноутбук перестал иницализироваться , то-есть я включаю ноутбук и только черный экран, даже биос не грузится , но если подключить HDMI, включается и ноут и экран на телеке, если забрать HDMI, все норм работает, ноут работает как ни в чем небывало , теперь что бы включить комп нужно втыкать HDMI , и только так он включается, в ремонте сказали хз по апаратке все ок, проблему тоже не нашли, помогите пж !

Comment: В BIOS для видеокарты нужно выбрать Init display first, или похожую опцию. Так же проблема может быть в настройках X сервера, если экран в начале загрузки виден.

Comment: в начале даже биос не видно , просто пусто

Comment: Значит точно это - какое то подобие Init display first ищите.

Comment: окей , спасибо , напишу если сработало или нет

Comment: Еле зашел в биос , почему-то в Boot есть два SSD, и два убунту , была только одна загрузка , есть идеи?

Comment: Может конфликт убунт ? хаха

Comment: Для начала я бы попробовал Load optimized default

Comment: Я грешил на убунту , а виноват биос , как я сразу недогодался , спасибо , если вийдет напишу , что было дальше...

Comment: Есть решение , сделал все до заводских настроек , дальше все почистил , оперативку ластиком, все от пили , все провода отключил и подключил, удалил убунту , и установил новую , и тогда все заработало ок. Даже не знаю в чем была проблема , я грешу на оперативку , старую , я почистил и там было немного пили , то ли грязи , спасибо за подсказку , если что делал через джампер(биос). Надеюсь кому-то в будущем поможет !
Почему через Джампер , потому что даже через HDMI, перестало заходить , попробовал через джампер , и все сработало, как по мне это крайня мера !